# Get the name of the column with the max value, but rows are not correlatives

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table:

[image]

I know how to get the max value between some specific cells:

```
=MAX(B2;B5;B6)  --4
```

I know how to get the name of the column searching inside all the table:

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(MAX(B2:B6),B2:B6,0))  --C
```

But I need to search just between some specific cells (B2, B5 and B6).  How should I write the formula?

Comment: Is there something else like another column that dictates which rows to use?

Comment: I must use rows 2, 4 and 6

Comment: which excel are you using?

Comment: It's Excel 2019

Comment: there must be some logic, something other than "I want these rows"  How is excel supposed to know what you want.  You will need something outside theses two columns to dictate which rows you want.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2:B6=MAX(INDEX((ISEVEN(ROW(B2:B6)))*(B2:B6),)))*(ISEVEN(ROW(B2:B6))),),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It works with even rows, but just for this example.  I am very sorry, I'll exchange the rows I need...

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>Microsoft365</kbd> you can try `XLookup()`.

```
=XLOOKUP(MAX(--ISEVEN(ROW(B2:B6))*B2:B6),--ISEVEN(ROW(B2:B6))*B2:B6,A2:A6)
```

Here `--ISEVEN(ROW(B2:B6))*B2:B6` make a array of even rows value like `2,0,5,0,1` max `MAX(--ISEVEN(ROW(B2:B6))*B2:B6)` will find max from these even rows. Hence `XLookup()` find max value position to that array and return text from `Column A` of corresponding value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It works with even rows, but just for this example.  I am very sorry, I'll exchange the rows I need...

Comment: @AlbertoMuñozSánchez Then `ISODD()`.

Comment: It's not even or odd.  They are B2, B5 and B6.

Comment: @AlbertoMuñozSánchez We have to give a logic to Excel. Otherwise how excel will know our mind?